# Creating URL searchable product variants

Tags: url-rewrite, magento-2.2.5, product-urls

In most e-commerce platforms, when a user selects a specific variant, the URL reflects that variant with a search parameter like in this case ->
[image: Shopify store URL]you can see **?variant=39817439379514** appended to the URL. If I use this specific URL, I will land on the page with the ‘Peppercorn’ and ‘L’ variants selected.

In magento, the URL remains static despite the variants that are selected as shown in the photos attached. Whenever I land on this magento product, no variant options will be selected. In the application I’m building, we want each variant to be searchable through specific URLs. [image][image]

I know you can change the product configurations to be visible by URL, but this creates a separate page for the variant, which is not the UI experience I want.

Does Magento support this functionality? If not, is there another way I can configure the store to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Magento offers the same functionality.
Append a hash to the url to preselect values and switch image to the selected variant.

For more details, see:
https://blog.chapagain.com.np/magent-2-load-configurable-product-with-options-pre-selected/

HTH, Tom

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this according to the below format

**https://example.com/configurable-product.html#202=230&105=123**

Format : #Attribute_ID=Value_ID

202 = Attribute ID
230 = Option value ID of the above attribute

105 = Attribute ID
123 = Option value ID of the above attribute