# Product variant URL with attribute and value IDs: doesn't switch image to selected one

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, product-images

In magento 2 is possible to call a specific product variant just appending to the "normal" URL:

```
#Attribute_ID=Value_ID
```

I've read in various posts that this functionality should also involve the switch of the image to the selected variant (for example [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/367133/creating-url-searchable-product-variants)).

**But does anyone know why in my shop Magento 2.3.6 this doesn't happen?**
The attribute inside < select > element correctly shitches to the variant, but the image remains on the first one... it could be related to the theme?

Thanks in advance to those who will respond!